# Is there any training for moderators?

Tags: support, moderators

Do diamond-moderators undergo any sort of training when they get elected? (That is above and beyond the experience they accumulated over the years)

Comment: This is a typical example of an XY-problem. You experience some issue (X), and as a result you start wondering about whether something else (Y) is going on. However, in general it's much better to ask about (X) directly. In other words, what is the problem?

Comment: They do it Dwarf Fortress way...

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. And I'd like to see people post their moderator training ideas in the comments below.

Comment: They spend years on the [wheel of pain](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/conan/images/2/20/Wheel_of_Pain.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131011092639).

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh: how will non-moderators know what diamond moderators do when they have no experience themselves? Are you perhaps confusing community moderation (done by regular members with high enough reputation) and elected moderators (of which there are only about [130 across the 38 Stack Exchange sites](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Stack-Overflow-Gives-Back-2016/) (of which [22 moderate SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)).

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh: Most of all, you are not exactly explaining that a) you are looking for suggestions and b) **why** you are collecting suggestions. What is your goal, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry sire, @zaq made a suggestion I quite like. I'll write up my own list, but before I submit it, I'd like to see if this is a quixotic idea, or if there are other people like me who feel that the way moderation  works may not be the best and there is way for improvement. And before I get any more hate-downvotes on my other post, this is not against you guys. I do appreciate the effort you've been putting into it for years. I know it is bloody hard word, did it myself long enough to know.

Comment: But I do not believe that all the "diamond-belt ninja trained the hard way" type of comments address the central issue: there is no formal training - that is - there is no process through which you would have an shared understanding of how to practice community moderation. And I a talking about elected mods, not the way the community does what it does. I am not seeking remedy to a particular sore. I am pointing out that those 22 people need space and time together to reach a consensus and establish benchmarks and best practices to take moderation to the next level.

Comment: So if this goes up in flames, and I am getting whacked for it, so be it.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh: community voting is *not punishment*. On Meta you don't gain or lose points from votes either. Now, if you have issues with how moderation works, why not *directly talk about that*? If brought constructively, preferably with some data, there is no reason anything is to go up in flames.

Comment: @MrLister Or maybe OP is curious about whether moderators receive training once elected.

Comment: @canon +1 for the conan reference. which is also a typo of your name :) +2 actually.

Comment: @MrLister The fact that something made the OP wonder if moderators undergo training is not a typical example of an XY problem

Comment: @aw04 My line of thinking is that in this particular case, something bad happened, and the OP assumed that was caused by a lack of training for the moderators, and now they're here asking for a solution to the lack of training, instead of asking for a solution to the "something bad". That better?

Comment: @MrLister It makes sense, but it takes many assumptions to get there

Comment: @aw04 - Probably just going by past experience with these types of questions on Meta plus the OP's own comments.

Answer (score 44):

Yes and no.

There are help materials available, and in the past, when new tools have  been introduced there have been 'training' chats in the Teachers Lounge that new moderators still have access to. And the existing moderators (those on Stack Overflow as well as moderators on other sites) and the Community Manager team provide a lot of guidance and support.

But there is no formal 'training programme', no. I don't think there is a need for one; developing one would be time consuming and expensive, while the current on-the-job training is pretty effective.

Comment: *Training on the job...*

Comment: So where do I request that to be added to the portfolio. @rene - that would require a normalised consensus about best practices. Proper training would help reach that consensus among the trainers, then training on the job would work.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh you lost me there. Your comment suggest that you have doubts about the elected diamond moderators?

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh if some of the Meta activities after the previous election are anything to go by, the community is more than willing to put newly elected moderators through their paces.

Comment: The old moderators train the new ones with [*whips and slashes*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Uae.gif). (GIF [source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/300471/1))

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh To directly answer "where do I request" -- here on Meta. Put up a new post tagged feature-request, proposing to introduce a formal training program as described in your comment. Stating some reasons why such a program is needed might help.

Comment: @BhargavRao I will never imagine the moderators in the same way again :(

Comment: @BhargavRao If that's the case, why haven't I... please no please _*ow!*_ I'm sorry! _*ow!*_

Comment: "Yes and no" - Schrödinger's training.

Comment: @MarounMaroun please remember to bring your cat to tonight's session of Schrödinger's training.

Comment: @BhargavRao after seeing your image i can see all mod have strong BASE :p

Comment: You should mention that all this support is "pull". There is no mandatory webinar or something like that.

Comment: @Raphael no, we give each other unasked advice too. Moderator actions are very transparent and especially for new mods the experienced hands look along and will speak out if there are things to improve.

Comment: There's a good amount of training *before* the job as a volunteer contributor to the site, no?

Answer (score 14):

(Source - I'm an elected mod on superuser. Ex-mod pro tem on software recommendations)

[Official Secret SO mod training site](https://stackoverflow.com/)

In a very practical sense, the time a user's spent *before* election is training. People get elected *because* enough people see them in a list of users who have stepped up for the role, decide these are folks who are the best suited from the options presented to them, and vote for them. They also work out the *tools* they have.

Outside the soft skills, which are impossible to train for, and flag processing (which I'm told mods here do a lot), *there's little that differentiates the powers of one or more high reputation users from a mod*. We literally have one more queue and a handful of additional tools, reflecting the greater level of trust.

I can unilaterally close questions on the site I'm a mod. A group of users can reopen them. While I do eliminate spammers - I had roughly 2000 spam flags *before* I was made mod, and I'm still only slightly faster than smokey assisted flags.

I use meta posts to influence *wider site policy* with a little extra weight cause of the diamond. I *occasionally* use it to help out other sites with chat moderation issues.

There's a *few* things that aren't exactly intuitive - spotting voting rings is more of an *art* than a *skill* in some cases and some mods are better than others. But things like that are why we have multiple mods per site.

Comment: There's special [larsoning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DndWh.png) training also

Comment: But can you Larson like The Larson?

Comment: Nah, I'm still undergoing training. I guess I'll soon be able to

Comment: Well, Brad did [write the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ycwi.png)

Comment: Soft skills are quite easy to train for. They just don't include objective answers to every question in the field, like hard skills do.