# What should we include in training for moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

Currently, [there is no comprehensive training process that would prepare newly elected moderators for the tasks they face](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341583/is-there-any-training-for-moderators).

There've been a few previous discussions on MSE aimed at giving folks a better idea of what to expect and how to acclimate:

- [Let's give a better idea of what moderators do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275845/lets-give-a-better-idea-of-what-moderators-do)
- [What advice do the veteran moderators have for the newly elected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222667/what-advice-do-the-veteran-moderators-have-for-the-newly-elected)

...But that advice is fairly general; nothing wrong with it, but for the most part it's just as applicable on Gardening as it is here. Nothin' wrong with generally good practices and strategies, but... Surely moderation here on Stack Overflow is at least a *little bit* special?

So, what sort of guidance should we be giving to new moderators *here* to help them hit the ground running?

1. ...What have y'all seen new mods struggle with, get blindsided, confused or frustrated by?
2. ...If you are or if you've been a moderator here, what lessons did you learn that you wished someone had taught you much, much sooner?

Comment: Please [refer to the comment I left on the revision](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/341601/revisions). If you want folks to discuss a matter with you, try & come at it with an open mind, specifying only what you want to know - don't dictate *how* those with knowledge must assist you. [I've moved the previous comment discussion to chat, as it mostly pertains to text I've removed.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/133232/discussion-on-question-by-lefty-g-balogh-what-should-we-include-in-training-for)

Comment: If this were on [meta.se], I'd ask for a sandbox where I could try destructive actions like redactions, merging posts and tags, since those happen rarely enough on other sites that you *don't* get to try them out, and when an actual need finally arises, you're not sure if you're going to mess up.

Comment: @muru This is a fair point - I didn't have much experience with some of these features from moderating a smaller, less active site - but I'm not sure it's really necessary. SO has the advantage of a much larger moderator group than other sites, so it's extremely easy to ask your fellow mods, "Hey, how do I do X?" And, of course, the mod tools prevent many hypothetically possible outcomes, anyway. I realize you probably already know this; I'm adding it more for the benefit of others who don't have access to diamond-mod tools anywhere.

Answer (score 16):

Especially on SO, training isn't necessary. You get to use the vast majority of the tools in your first week or two. Stack Exchange is awesome at naming most things clearly, and almost everything has a helpful tooltip.

The last batch of new blood learned the tools within a few weeks, and they're doing a great job. I don't see a reason to formalize the on-the-job training we already get.

Comment: I have nothing to add to this except to emphasize that SO has a large and basically always-on group of moderators. There's essentially *always* somebody online to provide guidance. And, of course, most of the day-to-day decisions are either really straightforward and obvious. The rest - especially the ones involving more exotic features - are typically not crises when they arise.